# Getting 404 for SignalR server in Angular MVC app

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, signalr

I'm attempting to add SignalR to my Angular MVC app having used [this](http://henriquat.re/server-integration/signalr/integrateWithSignalRHubs.html) article as a starting point.  I have it all setup, but when the following URL gets hit when the page loads, it returns a 404:

```
https://localhost/APPNAME/signalr/negotiate?clientProtocol=1.5&connectionData=%5B%5D&_=1452720381700
```

Here are my files:

App_Start/Starup.cs:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.MapSignalR();
    }
}
```

Hub:

```
public class CommissionsHub : Hub
{
    private static IHubContext hub = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<CommissionsHub>();

    public static void UpdatePendingPayment(PendingPaymentViewModel pendingPayment)
    {
        hub.Clients.All.onUpdatePendingPayment(pendingPayment);
    }
}
```

Factory:

```
app.factory('signalRUrl', ['baseUrl', function (baseUrl) {
    return baseUrl.substring(0, baseUrl.length - 1);
}]);

app.factory('hubProxy', ['$rootScope', 'signalRUrl', function ($rootScope, signalRUrl) {

    function hubProxyFactory(hubName) {
        var connection = $.hubConnection(signalRUrl);
        var proxy = connection.createHubProxy(hubName);

        connection.start().done(function () { });

        return {
            on: function (eventName, callback) {
                proxy.on(eventName, function (result) {
                    $rootScope.$apply(function () {
                        if (callback) {
                            callback(result);
                        }
                    });
                });
            },
            invoke: function (methodName, callback) {
                proxy.invoke(methodName)
                .done(function (result) {
                    $rootScope.$apply(function () {
                        if (callback) {
                            callback(result);
                        }
                    });
                });
            },
            connection: connection
        };
    };

    return hubProxyFactory;
}]);
```

Controller:

```
angular.module('testApp').controller('testController', ['$scope', 'hubProxy', 
    function ($scope, hubProxy) {

        var commissionsHub = hubProxy('commissionsHub');

        commissionsHub.on('onUpdatePendingPayment', function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        });
    }]);
```

I have a bundle in my BundleConfig that is referencing jquery-2.1.4.js and jquery.signalR-2.2.0.js.

What am I missing?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like my problem is that there was another Owin Startup class (another dev created) which the one I created was conflicting with.  I added my SignalR startup configuration to the other Owin startup file and the signalr URL works now.